# Alternative to using strings.Builder in conjunction with fmt.Sprintf

Tags: go

I am learning about the `strings` package in Go and I am trying to build up a simple error message.

I read that `strings.Builder` is a very eficient way to join strings, and that `fmt.Sprintf` lets me do some string interpolation.

With that said, I want to understand the best way to join a lot of strings together. For example here is what I create:

```
func generateValidationErrorMessage(err error) string {
    errors := []string{}

    for _, err := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
        var b strings.Builder
        b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("[%s] failed validation [%s]", err.Field(), err.ActualTag()))
        if err.Param() != "" {
            b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", err.Param()))
        }
        errors = append(errors, b.String())
    }

    return strings.Join(errors, "; ")
}
```

Is there another/better way to do this? Is using `s1 + s2` considered worse?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. Your strings are short, you do not build from many parts, this is (hopefully) not the hot code path. Ignore such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fmt` to print directly to the `strings.Builder`. Use `fmt.Fprintf(&builder, "format string", args)`.

The [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#pkg-index) functions beginning with `Fprint...`, meaning "file print", allow you to print to an `io.Writer` such as a `os.File` or `strings.Builder`.

Also, rather than using multiple builders and joining all their strings at the end, just use a single builder and keep writing to it. If you want to add a separator, you can do so easily within the loop:

```golang
var builder strings.Builder
for i, v := range values {
    if i > 0 {
        // unless this is the first item, add the separator before it.
        fmt.Fprint(&builder, "; ")
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(&builder, "some format %v", v)
}

var output = builder.String()
```

Comment: Like for concise way for first/last element detection